# java transaction.rollback() not rollbacking the DB

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, entitymanager

I try to do transactions on my project java, and I realise all transactions don't rollback the rows in DB.
It's a local project (the DB was MySQL on phpmyadmin, all tables in innoDB).

I try to do an insert (with a transaction), execute an exeption, and rollback the insert DB.

here an exemple of block transaction I use.

```
EntityManager em = EMF.getEM();
BasketService basketService = new basketService();
EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();

try{
  transaction.begin();
  Basket basket = new Basket();
  //set basket params.
  basketService.insert(em, basket);
  if(basket.getId() != 0) //if inserted.
    throw new Exception("fake error");
  transaction.commit();
}catch(Exception e){
  transaction.rollback();
  //print error.
}finally{
  if(transaction.isActive()) //security.
    transaction.rollback();
  em.close();
}
```

here an exemple of service I use.

```
public class BasketService {
  public Basket insert(EntityManager em, Basket basket){
    em.persist(basket);
    em.flush();
    return basket;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just run the code and see if it inserts or rolls back?

Comment: I do, but it stay inserted on DB (after catch the exception). as like the rollback was called, but don't working.

Comment: 1) are you sure the Exception is being thrown? 2) not sure what framework is being used/how it works, but is the connection/transaction set to autocommit?

Comment: I'm sur it bass into the catch, and it continue after the transtion.rollback().
for the second point, I haven't see any attribute autocommit on the entityManager or  transaction.
I use javax.persistence javax.transaction-api 1.3

Comment: Just do a println above the commit to see if it executes, or use a debugger.

Comment: I have try with a log.info upper and lower every line using the object transaction (commit, rollback, ...) and it was call normaly has expected. like rollback was call with success and without any error wen I throw an exception, and commit was call with success to if I'm not throwing exception. But in my DB, the row inserted was stay inserted in both situation.

Comment: did you check your server configuration? what about setting the jta property in datasource? is it true or false?

Comment: for the server config I don't know what param verify except Autocommit.
I don't see jta property in variable/parameters server.
I have just `<persistence-unit name="gamepath" transaction-type="JTA">` in persistence.xml

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that auto commit is enabled on your mysql database (probably default behaviour)

Let’s try setting the property « hibernate.connection.autocommit » to false in your persistence.xml

Comment: I have try with the property « hibernate.connection.autocommit », but the same result was appear : error throw, catch, and row stil in DB.
Also I try to make delete with transaction right from the console SQL of phpmyadmin, and the transaction was rollback (if it can help to reduce the range of possibilities).

Comment: Did you try w/o flushing?

Comment: I have try with no flush but the DB take no changes, I also try with only one flush before transition.commit, but I son't see any diference comparate to making flush after any action.

Comment: I have try again this solution, it seem work, except on the situation when I have to make many insert in one transaction (if the first is not flush, I can get the ID of the first for insert another entity who need the foreign key of the first entity).

Answer (score 0):

Check you server configuration. By setting **jta=false** in standalone datasource, **em.rollback()** might only rollback changes within the EntityManager's persistence context. This means:
Changes flushed to the database using **em.flush()** might not be rolled back.
The database could end up in an inconsistent state, with some data persisted even though the transaction ultimately failed.

Comment: I don't find the option for jta=false in server parameters, is it something so set in persistance.xml or pom.xml ?